# What function does the loop of displaying posts?

Tags: posts, functions, loop, pages

What is the function that does the echoing of posts like post title in h1 and then the post body and then the author name. I hope everyone understood what I'm trying to say else please ask in comments I'll explain.

Comment: What research have you completed so far on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Here's a standard loop you can customize using WP_Query.

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You can add the_content and entry meta to the loop using get_template_part, a template tag or hard coding it into the loop.

Here's a loop included in the Twenty Fourteen themes single.php file.

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_post_nav();

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    comments_template();
                }
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

The author name is included in the Post Info which in the Twenty Fourteen theme has been coded as a template tag

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_posted_on' ) ) :
/**
 * Print HTML with meta information for the current post-date/time and author.
 */
function twentyfourteen_posted_on() {

// Set up and print post meta information.
printf( '<span class="entry-date"><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a></span> <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" rel="author">%5$s</a></span></span>',
    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    get_the_author()
);
}
endif;
```

Then the template tag is included in the content.php file

```
twentyfourteen_posted_on();
```

And the content.php included in the single.php file using get_template_part.

```
get_template_part( 'content' );
```

Answer (score 1):

***No single function*** "does the echoing of posts like post title in h1 and then the post body and then the author name". There are a set of functions called [template tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags), as subset of which-- the [post tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags)-- are for retrieving or displaying post content. It is up to you to organize your post content display however you like.